# React - API call with Axios, how to bind an onClick event with an API Call

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I have one component, which is handle input component

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import FacebookApiCall from './Api'

export default function FacebookInterest () {
    const [interest, setInterest] = useState('');

    function HandleChange(event) {
        setInterest(event.target.value);
    }

    return (
    <div className="maincontainer">
      <input className="searchbar" type="text" placeholder="Type an interest ..." value={interest} onChange={HandleChange}/>
      <button onClick={() => FacebookApiCall(interest)} className="searchbutton">Search</button>
    </div>
    );
}
```

When a user click, i want to make a call to the API thanks to FacebookApiCall which is

```js
    import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
    import axios from 'axios'


export default function FacebookApiCall(props) {
    
    const url = `https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=adinterest&q=${props}&limit=10000&locale=en_US&access_token=EA`
    
     useEffect(() => {
         axios.get(url)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(url);
                console.log(res);
                
                //console.log(res.data.data[62].audience_size);
                //console.log(res.data.data[62].name);
                //console.log(res.data.data[62].description);
                //console.log(res.data.data[62].path);
            })
        });
        return (null);
}
```

the error returned by react is :

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
```

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

So I can't use a hooks inside my Facebook function i understand that now how can i make an api call without using useEffect and if I have to use useEffect no matter what, what i'm supposed to do ? I have to admit that im lost here.

Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 2):

So it looks like you're breaking one of the rules of hooks:

> Only Call Hooks from React Functions

In your `FacebookApiCall` you're calling the useEffect hook from a non-react function.

The proper way to do this would be to do your api call from a function in your component.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function FacebookInterest () {
   const url = `https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=adinterest&q=${props}&limit=10000&locale=en_US&access_token=EA`
   const [interest, setInterest] = useState(null);
   const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);

   useEffect(() => {
      // If you want do do some other action after
      // the response is set do it here. This useEffect will only fire
      // when response changes.
   }, [response]); // Makes the useEffect dependent on response.

   function callYourAPI() {
      axios.get(url).then(res => {
         // Handle Your response here.
         // Likely you may want to set some state
         setResponse(res);
      });
   };

   function HandleChange(event) {
      setInterest(event.target.value);
   };

   return (
      <div className="maincontainer">
         <input
           className="searchbar"
           type="text"
           placeholder="Type an interest ..."
           value={interest}
           onChange={HandleChange}
         />
         <button
           onClick={() => callYourAPI(interest)}   
           className="searchbutton"
           // You may want to disable your button until interest is set
           disabled={interest === null}
         >
           Search
         </button>
      </div>
   );
};
```